# Js.js_array from Javascript; coerce, get/set

Tags: arrays, ocaml, js-of-ocaml

I have an array of objects in my Javascript file that I need to access from js_of_ocaml. I've come up with this so far:

```
let table_decks = (Js.Unsafe.variable "table_decks" :> 
  < deck_nr : int > Js.js_array Js.t)
```

In Javascript, the array will be like `table_decks = {{deck_nr: 10, ...}, {deck_nr: 20, ...}}` with more fields than just `deck_nr`.

My question is: How do I access this array? I find a lot of functions in `Js.js_array`, but no get/set.

(Another question is if the coerce is in fact correct?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Js.array_get/array_set or Js.Unsafe.get/set.

```
val array_get : 'a #js_array t -> int -> 'a optdef
val array_set : 'a #js_array t -> int -> 'a -> unit
```

To support overloading on ocaml, js_of_ocaml removes letters after last _ in javascript name.
So "deck_nr" becames "deck" in generated js, so add another "_".

Put all it together...

```
let table_decks = (Js.Unsafe.variable "table_decks" :>
  < deck_nr_ : int Js.prop > Js.t Js.js_array Js.t)

let get a n =
  match Js.Optdef.to_option (Js.array_get a n) with
  | Some n -> n##deck_nr_
  | None -> 0
```